# Add untyped JavaScript options property to declared class

Tags: typescript, koa-router

I'm working with the `koa-router` type declarations from the [DefinitelyTyped repository](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/koa-router). The class declaration does not include a definition for the `opts` property, which means that attempting to access the property will produce a TS2339 error.

Aside from non-typed workarounds, e.g. `(routerObj as any).opts.<option>`, how can I add/extend this property with the types from IRouterOptions to the already existing definition?

***Edit***

I tried [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation), but I was unsuccessful in doing so:

```
import Router from 'koa-router';

declare module 'koa-router' {
  class Router {
    opts: Router.IRouterOptions
  }
}
```

And following the documentation bit above

```
import Router from 'koa-router';

declare module 'koa-router' {
  interface Router<T> {
    opts: Router.IRouterOptions
  }
}
```

Neither of these worked. The error message I get from VSCode is also quite strange, which leads me to believe TS treats my attempt on augmentation and the DefinitelyTyped definitions as independent definitions: `Property 'opts' does not exist on type 'import("/Absolute/Path/To/node_modules/@types/koa-router/index.d.ts")'.`

However, augmenting another interface from the DefinitelyTyped definitions does work:

```
import Router from 'koa-router';

declare module 'koa-router' {
  interface IRouterOptions {
    requiredVar: boolean;
  }
}
```

This will produce a `TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IRouterOptions'. Property 'requiredVar' is missing in type '{}'.`

Comment: See [declaration merging - module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation). Also please create a PR if you fix an issue with a DT definition. :)

Comment: I wasn't able to augment the class definition, it seemed like TS treated my file and the DT as two independent declarations. I thought my syntax was incorrect, so I tried augmenting a couple of the interfaces in my file, and that worked just fine.

Comment: Edited my question to add some more details :)

Comment: Try putting the `import` *inside* your `declare module` block.

Comment: Using the same examples as above, with the `import` inside the `declare module` block, the first example produced a `TS2440 Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'Router'` with the squiggly line below `Router` in the `import Router` statement. In the second case, the squiggly line is below `Router` in the `opts: Router.IRouterOptions` with the following error: `TS2702: Router' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.`

Comment: Perhaps the only solution is to modify the DT definitions itself?

Comment: Argh! The second case in my above comment is incorrect. The following is the correct scenario: The squiggly line is below `IRouterOptions` in the `opts: Router.IRouterOptions` statement. The error is: `TS2694: Namespace ''koa-router'' has no exported member 'IRouterOptions'`